# -fPIC error crosscompile openssl

Tags: c++, openssl, arm, cross-compiling

Executing an cross-compiled version of openssl for armv5l result in the following error message.
How to fix this ?:

```
Can't modify /usr/local/ssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0's text section. Use GCC option -fPIC for shared objects, please.
```

**Details:**

i used the following cross-compiler:
http://uclibc.org/downloads/binaries/0.9.30.1/cross-compiler-armv5l.tar.bz2

I comipled openssl for armv5l using:

```
export PATH=/home/toff/workspaces/armv5l/cross-compiler-armv5l/bin:$PATH
export cross=armv5l-
export CFLAGS=-fPIC
./Configure linux-generic32 -DL_ENDIAN --openssldir=/lib -fPIC

make CC="${cross}gcc" AR="${cross}ar r" RANLIB="${cross}ranlib" LD="${cross}ld" MAKEDEFPROG="${cross}gcc" PROCESSOR=ARM

make CC="${cross}gcc" AR="${cross}ar r" RANLIB="${cross}ranlib" LD="${cross}ld" MAKEDEFPROG="${cross}gcc" PROCESSOR=ARM INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/package-root install
```

and if i look up the Makefile, -fPIC seems to be configured:

```
CFLAG= -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DL_ENDIAN -fPIC -DTERMIO -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall
```

Answer (score 1):

`CFLAG` is not the same as `CFLAGS`. It's supposed to be `CFLAGS`.

And, once that's fixed, no matter what you `export` from your shell, `CFLAGS` is overwritten in the makefile.

Comment: ok, thanks. so the export CFLAGS=-fPIC is useless. But still through ./Configure -fPIC the CFLAG is defined in the Makefile  (see last quote). or ?

Comment: You just did it again. Did you even read my answer?